# Synergy : Impossible to put @ in outlook 2003

Tags: microsoft-outlook, synergy

I'm using Synergy 1.3.6, with server being on a Ubuntu 10.10 x64 machine, and a client on windows xp 32 bits.

When using Synergy, it is impossible for me to put any "@" in outlook 2003. However it works in other apps like notepad.

Has anybody already been confronted to this bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically like this, but I have had problems with the @ sign before.

I cured it by adding this to the synergy.conf file:

```
section: options
    keystroke(Shift+Apostrophe) = keystroke(At)
end
```

Of course, that's for the UK keymap - replace the Shift+Apostrophe for your actual key combination for the @ sign.